# mod_rewrite is not working after take [R:Redirect] out

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I using CodeIgniter and are trying to rewrite url for SEO friendly.
The purpose would be...

```
http://localhost/FOR-SEO/item/view/id
-> to -> http://localhost/item/view/id
```

(just wanna leave FOR-SEO out)

I tried to add htaccess as follow,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/view/(.*)$ /item/view/$2 [R,L]
```

so it become...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/view/(.*)$ /item/view/$2 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It work fine, but after i take [R] out it show 404 errors not found.

i tried to check the rewrite log but everything is the same for both with [R] and without [R]

here is the log with [R] (working)

```
[rid#1009868a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] escaping http://localhost:8888/item/view/2 for redirect
[rid#1009868a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] redirect to http://localhost:8888/item/view/2 [REDIRECT/302]
[rid#10098a8a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] internal redirect with /index.php/item/view/2 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#100984da8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] pass through /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/index.php
[rid#1009978a0/subreq] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] internal redirect with /index.php/item/view/2 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

here is the log without [R], (not working)

```
[localhost/sid#100813108][rid#10098f8a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] internal redirect with /item/view/2 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[localhost/sid#100813108][rid#100993a50/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] internal redirect with /index.php/item/view/2 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[localhost/sid#100813108][rid#100991828/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] pass through /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/index.php
[localhost/sid#100813108][rid#1009978a0/subreq] (1) [perdir /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/himaparn/] internal redirect with /index.php/item/view/2 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

What wrong with this, and do i have any better solution to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the `[R]` [forces an external redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) in which case the base is already set and the path is appended to the redirect end-points' base url.

So, with `[R]`, a request to `http://example.com/index.php/item/view/2`, `/index.php/item/view/2` will be appended to `http://example.com/` leaving you with `http://example.com/index.php/item/view/2`

Without the `[R]` you are getting an internal redirect. This will append `/index.php/item/view/2` to the request. So requesting `http://example.com/index.php/item/view/2` will leave you with `http://example.com/index.php/item/view/2/index.php/item/view/2` netting you a `404`.

You can pretty clearly see the multiple redirects in the log:

> ...
>   [rid#100993a50/initial/redir#1]...
>   [rid#100991828/initial/redir#2]...
>   ...

Comment: So do you have any idea to make the same result?

Comment: If it works with `[R]`, why don't you leave it? What is the problem? What is the desired result?

Comment: I want to make a seo friendly url. Put the [R] wil change the url the the result. But i want the search engine to see my mask url.

Comment: Try using a full URL in the rewrite: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/view/(.*)$ http://example.com/item/view/$2 [L]`